# Django | the role of the environment vatiable?

Tags: python, django, linux, web

I'm learning Django and I come across something.
We use environment variables to keep secrets safe from others or to hide them from other developers who work on the same project.
We can export the variables on the server.

```
import os
SECRET = os.environ.get("")
```

But then any developer can print this secret and see it. What is the point of using environment variables?

Comment: There are many reasons to do this, but here are two: (a) they are environment-specific, so it's easy to use different ones in development, staging, production, etc., and (b) they are not committed to version control so you can keep sensitive information out of your source code.

Comment: Your production server/environment, especially if it contains user data, should be extremely secure and not accessible to anyone without authorization and each access logged. The same restrictions do not apply to your source code